# How can I fix my offlineimap Certificate error on a homebrew install

Tags: homebrew, ssl

```
OfflineIMAP 7.3.3
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
imaplib2 v2.101 (bundled), Python v2.7.17, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
*** Processing account charles
Establishing connection to secure.emailsrvr.com:993 (charles-Remote)
ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host 'secure.emailsrvr.com' for repository 'charles-Remote'. OpenSSL responded:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)
*** Finished account 'charles' in 0:00
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host 'secure.emailsrvr.com' for repository 'charles-Remote'. OpenSSL responded:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)

Traceback:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 293, in syncrunner
    self.__sync()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 372, in __sync
    remoterepos.getfolders()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 452, in getfolders
    imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 655, in acquireconnection
    exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 569, in acquireconnection
    af=self.af,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/imaplibutil.py", line 202, in __init__
    super(WrappedIMAP4_SSL, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 2191, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, debug, debug_file, identifier, timeout, debug_buf_lvl)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 360, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/imaplibutil.py", line 210, in open
    super(WrappedIMAP4_SSL, self).open(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 2204, in open
    self.ssl_wrap_socket()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/offlineimap/7.3.3/libexec/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 554, in ssl_wrap_socket
    self.sock = ctx.wrap_socket(self.sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 369, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 599, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 828, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

Comment: I have changed the certificate several times. Uninstalled and reinstalled offlineimap;   It just stopped working one day out of the blue.

Comment: I am not even sure if the problem is certificate verification or 

         ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host

Comment: If it stopped working out of the blue: did you check whether the certificate is still valid? Have there been any changes on server side? Does https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/issues/573 help?